# MYSQL copy two rows into one row in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table1 that looks like this:

```
id col1 col2
1   A   B
2   C   D
3   E   F
4   G   H
```

and need to copy 2 rows at the time and insert into one row in table2, as this:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
1   A    B    C    D
2   E    F    G    H
```

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use a simple `join`:

```
insert into table2(id,col1,col2,col3,col4)
select distinct id,t1.col1,t1.col2.t2.col1,t2.col2
from table1 t1 join table1 t2 on t2.id=t1.id+1
```